Dependency Injection is not working on any of my Livewire 3 components
I'm facing a very weird issue. Dependency injection is not working, and I don't have any clue why it isn't. Here's my component:
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Forms;

use App\Enums\CourseType;
use App\Repositories\Interfaces\ICourseRepository;
use BenSampo\Enum\Rules\EnumValue;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Livewire\Component;

class Course extends Component
{
    private ICourseRepository $_courses;
    public $heading;
    public $categories;

    ....

    public function mount(ICourseRepository $courses, $heading = 'Add Course')
    {
        $this->_courses = $courses;
        $this->heading = $heading;
    }

    ...
    public function create()
    {
        $this->reset(); // Reset all fields
        $this->categories = $this->_courses->allCategories(); // Fetch all categories
        $this->dispatch('openCourseModal', ['title' => 'কোর্স যোগ করুন']); // Dispatch an event to open the modal
    }
    ...

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.forms.course');
    }
}


Here, the click method is bound to the wire:click event. The exception I'm encountering is:
Error
PHP 8.3.4
10.48.20
Typed property App\Livewire\Forms\Course::$_courses must not be accessed before initialization

Can you please help me get through this? Thank you for your attention.

Ok, I found that the dependency injection does work. I used dd($this->_courses->allCategories()); inside the mount method, and I got the data. So why is it not working in the create method, even after assigning it to a public property?

If you look carefully at the error message you will get the reason behind this error:

Typed property App\Livewire\Forms\Course::$_courses must not be accessed before initialization.

Which means you need to initialize $_courses on the class constructor.
You can simply make the $_courses property nullable to prevent initialization errors:
protected ?ICourseRepository $_courses = null;

So the initial value is null but later in the mount method it will get resolved using DI.

Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, that does not work either. Now i have this error: Call to a member function allCategories() on null

@raizul Can you please check the recent comment on the question?

This is not related to the previous issue.

Can you make sure the dependency injection working properly or not?

The issue could be that your component is called many times in the application, but as specified in the livewire lifecycle hooks documentation, the mount() method is executed only once when the component is created, so when other actions are performed in the application, the service will no longer be injected, as mount() will not be executed until the next page reload.
If you need to use the ICourseRepository many times during the lifecycle of your Course component then you should inject it via the boot() method that is called at the beginning of every request.
Here's an exemple :
public function boot(ICourseRepository $courses, $heading = 'Add Course')
{
    $this->_courses = $courses;
    $this->heading = $heading;
}

I hope this will help

Also note that livewire methods will also resolve dependencies. So, in this case, the service could be injected directly in the create() method, so it is only being resolved for the method that needs it, and not on every request to the component. public function create(ICourseRepository $courses)
